# Algorithm Efficiency

Tags: performance, algorithm

So this is a question in my homework....

> Given that the efficiency of an algorithm is n<sup>3</sup>, if a step in the algorithm takes 1 ns (10<sup>-9</sup>) seconds), how long does it take the algorithm to process an input of size 1,000?

Here is MY question: How do I figure this out? PLEASE DO NOT POST THE ANSWER. Help me learn how to figure this out for myself.

Comment: +1 Props for asking specifically NOT for the answer

Comment: +1 for not using the deprecated 'homework' tag.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Can anyone confirm the answer is 1 second?

Comment: I'm really sad the 1 attosecond answer was deleted :(

Comment: @AK4749 indeed :/ and before the edit it was actually 1 zeptosecond.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You define `n` to be `1000`. Thus, you need n<sup>3</sup> steps, each one of them taking `1 ns`. Multiply the two and you have the answer.

General idea: if an algorithm needs `f(n)` number of steps and one step takes `t` then you need `t * f(n)` for the algorithm.

Comment: I understand now. So the answer is 1 second?

Comment: Yep, it is 1 second. Of course, if there are some constants involved in `n^3` the runtime will be different. But at least you have a guess on the order of magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

The `n` in `n^3` refers to data size in this case.  If you have an input of size 1, insert that into n^3.  (and then multiply it by the time.)  If you have an input of size 1,000... what should you do?

EDIT: Originally I posted this in Big-Oh notation (such as `O(n^3)`), which was flawed, as it ignores possible fixed costs that would make the question unanswerable as posted.  I feel I should leave this answer up, perhaps mostly as a reminder to others not to make the same mistake that I did.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The question notably does not use Big-O notation, otherwise it would not be answerable as stated. If it were `O(n^3)` a significant portion of input size one cost could be fixed costs of lower order variable cost terms that would be less important for larger inputs sizes.

Comment: That's true.  I will edit my response to incorporate your comment.